# Maintenance of metallic hydraulic disc brake pistons?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I have Tektro Auriga HD-M290 hydraulic disc brakes and they have metal piston. One of the pistons sticks out more than the other and they don't come out much even though I squeeze the brake lever many times. What I have handy is a red colored grease oil. Can I use it to lubricate the pistons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whatever is inside the hydraulic line, in this case mineral oil.

Use a cotton bud soaked in oil to lubricate the sides of the piston.

Attempt to cycle the pistons while holding the good side in with a large flathead screwdriver or something that won’t scratch or damage the piston.

Comment: +1, but adding the tip that it's a good idea to extend the pistons a touch past the normal limit, then clean thoroughly, then apply the fluid.